# serialization of static immutable objects(String) and static mutable object(Singleton class objects) in java

Tags: java, serialization, singleton

i am a bit confuse about serialization of static variables as they cannot be serialization. Although singleton class objects can be serialization.
    i have a sample code:

1. in `TestSerilization` class: i first compiled an run the code without
   comments i got the result, but as i comment the part and recompile
   and run i didnot got the desired result for static String values
   while de-serialization
2. in `TestSerilization2` class: i first compiled an run the code without comments i got the result, but as i comment the part and
   recompile and run i did got the same result for private static
   Student instance  values while de-serialization.

   i want to ask that why the `private static Student` instance gave values but private `static String name` didn't, although both are `static`.

```
    import java.io.*;
    class Student implements Serializable{
        private static String  name;
        private int rollNo;

        public void setName(String name){
            this.name=name;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setRollNo(int rollNo){
            this.rollNo=rollNo;
        }
        public int getRollNo(){
            return this.rollNo;
        }
    }
    public class TestSerilization{
        public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
            /*
            Student s1=new Student();
            s1.setName("Apoorv");
            s1.setRollNo(13);

            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\JAVA Practice\\output.ser"));
            oos.writeObject(s1);
            System.out.println("s1: name-"+s1.getName()+" rollno-"+s1.getRollNo()+" hascode: "+s1.hashCode());
            */
            ObjectInputStream ins=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\JAVA Practice\\output.ser"));
            Student s2=(Student)ins.readObject();
            System.out.println("s2: name-"+s2.getName()+" rollno-"+s2.getRollNo()+" hascode: "+s2.hashCode());
        }
    }




    import java.io.*;
    final class Student implements Serializable{
        private static Student instance;
        private String  name;
        private int rollNo;

        private Student(){} 
        public static Student getInstance(){
            if(instance==null){
                instance=new Student();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public void setName(String name){
            this.name=name;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setRollNo(int rollNo){
            this.rollNo=rollNo;
        }
        public int getRollNo(){
            return this.rollNo;
        }
    }
    public class TestSerilization2{
        public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
            /*
            Student s1=Student.getInstance();
            s1.setName("Apoorv");
            s1.setRollNo(13);
            System.out.println("s1: name-"+s1.getName()+" rollno-"+s1.getRollNo()+" hascode: "+s1.hashCode());
            Student s2=Student.getInstance();
            System.out.println("s2: name-"+s2.getName()+" rollno-"+s2.getRollNo()+" hascode: "+s2.hashCode());
            */

            /*
            Student s1=Student.getInstance();
            s1.setName("Apoorv");
            s1.setRollNo(13);

            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\JAVA Practice\\output2.ser"));
            oos.writeObject(s1);
            System.out.println("s1: name-"+s1.getName()+" rollno-"+s1.getRollNo()+" hascode: "+s1.hashCode());
            */
            ObjectInputStream ins=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\JAVA Practice\\output2.ser"));
            Student s2=(Student)ins.readObject();
            System.out.println("s2: name-"+s2.getName()+" rollno-"+s2.getRollNo()+" hascode: "+s2.hashCode());

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `private static Student instance`?

Comment: Why is `name` static?   (Generally speaking, there shouldn't be any static fields in any program except static constants.)

Comment: Hi Andy,  "private static Student instance" is declared in Student class

Comment: @AndyTurner  I have written written Student class code twice in same block.    1. Student class with "private static String  name" which is not a Singleton design and     2. Student class with  "private static Student instance" is a Singleton design. Both class need to be run individually.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the "`private static Student instance` gave values" when serialized, and that the "`private static String name` didn't", but what you are comparing is different from what you think your are comparing. You seem to think that in the first example you saw values when serializing `private static Student instance` but didn't when serializing `private static String name`, but you never serialized `private static String name`. Actually, you saw values when serializing a `Student` instance **with `String name`** and didn't when serializing a `Student` instance **with `static String name`**.
To clarify,

- In the 1st example, the `name` field IS `static`, and it IS NOT serialized.
- In the 2nd example, the `name` field IS NOT `static`, and it IS serialized.

A field marked as `static` indicates that it is owned by the class, which is why they are referenced via the class (`MyClass.field`) rather than via an instance (`((MyClass) instance).field`). Since you are dealing with Java ***object*** serialization, the `static` fields are not serialized as part of the object.

Whether or not a reference to an object is static is irrelevant when serializing *that* object. I.e. `Student student` (non-static reference) will serialize just the same as `static Student student` (static reference).